# Atualizar campo busca em uma página após x tempo da consulta

Tags: html, wordpress, formulário, input, div

Estou fazendo um terminal de consulta usando *WordPress* + *Woocommerce*, como irei utilizar leitor de código de barras e terá ZERO interação com teclado e mouse, preciso que o campo recarregue automaticamente alguns segundos após a consulta.

Tentei todas a possibilidades possíveis, mas não tive sucesso, o que chegou mais perto do que preciso foi com `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="10;">`, o problema é que a página atualiza a cada X segundos e muitas vezes coincide com o momento de leitura do código de barras. Eu preciso que esse refresh seja a X segundos após do código ser inserido.

Segue abaixo o código que estou utilizando e o link da página com o terminal de consulta.

A `div` é busca personalizada com um widget que consulta o banco do *Woocommerce*.

Precisei usar `onKeypress` no `input` search para desabilitar o enter, pois sempre que o leitor faz a leitura de um código ele executa enter e acaba carregando a página de produto do *e-commerce*, preciso que continue na mesma página exibindo a mini consulta do produto.

**Código**

```
<div class="ysm-search-widget ysm-search-widget-3 ysm-active"><form data-id="3" role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="https://eabeer.com.br/"> <label> <span class="screen-reader-text">Código de Barras</span> <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Código de Barras" value="" name="s" autocomplete="off" autofocus onKeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) event.returnValue = false;"><button type="submit" class="search-submit"><span class="screen-reader-text">Search</span></button> </label><div class="smart-search-results" style="max-height: 400px; width: 1120px;"><div class="smart-search-suggestions" style="position: absolute; display: none; max-height: 400px; z-index: 9999; width: 1120px;"></div></div></form></div>
```

Comment: Vc tem acesso ao código que faz a consulta, o Ajax?

Comment: Sam, acesso eu tenho, mas como disse, estou usando um Widget personalizado de busca que gera um `shortcode`, que no caso é o `ysm-search-widget-3`. 

Ajudaria passar o código mesmo assim?

Comment: Sim, porque vc pode colocar um código que atualiza a página após a consulta.

Comment: Após a consulta, coloque `setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 3000);`... isso irá atualizar a página após 3 segundos

Comment: Nesse caso, tenho que colocar esse código no arquivo do plugin de Busca personalizada, correto? Caso seja isso, fica complicado, pois esse plugin  é utilizado para o E-commerce também.

Comment: VC pode colocar dentro de um if que verifica a página onde vc quer que seja atualizada, aí só vai recarregar naquela página específica.

Comment: Sam, vou fingir que sei fazer para não passar vergonha, rs. 
Se não for abusar, como faço para inserir esse IF? Estava colocando o código do plugin aqui, mas ficou mto extenso e confuso.

Comment: Esse código que vc passou não mostra o processo.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas me parece que a função com a resposta da pesquisa é esta `onSearchComplete: function (query, suggestions) {`. Teria que testar com um console.log("ok"). Depois que enviar o código de barra e aparecer o resultado da pesquisa, veja se executa o console.log

Comment: Sam, tentei N opções, mas nenhuma executa o console.log. :( Muito obrigada pela disposição em ajudar.